# php - xampp apache not finding my application folder

Tags: php, html, macos, apache, xampp

My apache service won't run and I get the error:

```
ERROR: Failed to start "apache": cannot start service: AH00526: Syntax 
error on line 229 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs' is not a 
directory, or is not readable
```

I'm trying to change my documentroot and directory to

DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"

Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">

I've tried a handful of solutions and nothing has been working.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I am using a MAC OS X

EDIT_2: I think it might have something to do with the serverroot but I am not sure.

```
ServerRoot "/opt/lampp"
```

Comment: Is the directory readable?

Comment: I believe so, I made it readable and writeable just incase.